# How to decide grass seeds?

Tags: grass, seeds, lawn-repair

I had a big weed problem that I am eradicating. But I have big patches of soil and my aim is to turn my lawn into lush garden for sitting.

Half my garden get gold sunlight and half of it get shady and partial.

I am in north west of UK. What is the best grass seed and what should I look for?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's unlikely you will be able to remove the clover that is already there but it does add nitrogen to the soil and is attractive to bees.  Is your idea of a lush lawn only grass?

Comment: @kevinskio yes ATM grass, I wanna master the lush lawn with strips, I do have other ideas but not at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Consider removing the larger weeds by hand and then use a Feed, Weed and Mosskiller across the entire lawn, but using it before the cold weather comes would be ideal!

Then look to sow the best grass seed for shade.